# Pass Parameter into ViewModel constructor dependent on navigation region?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a WPF Application that i try to move to Prism step by step. The current step is RegionManager and NavigationService / Composite UI.

I did implement a own RegionManager and NavigationService to deal with the details, now i try to replace the own implementation with the Prism RegionManager (because it contains some functionality that would be nice) here is the problem i try to solve:

I have a TabControl which is able to display multiple contents that do not have anything to do with each other (like a browser). The TabControl has a Template set which creates a new Region for each Content to display (so i have a NavigationService and a Journey for each TabItem)

```
<userInterface:TabControlHelper.Template>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ContentViewModel}">
        <ContentControl x:Name="DataContextProxy">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{Binding ElementName=DataContextProxy, Path=DataContext.(viewModels:ContentViewModel.Id)}"
                            prism:RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=views:ContentOverview}, Path=DataContext.RegionManager}"
                            Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"
                            DataContext="{x:Null}" />
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</userInterface:TabControlHelper.Template>
```

now when the `TabControl.SelectedItem` is changed to a new Content I navigate to the HomeView Using the following code:

```
regionManager.Regions[this.SelectedContent.Id].RequestNavigate("HomeView");
```

The navigation works fine, just the ViewModel creation does not:
In my own implementation i handled the `AutoWireViewModel`AttachedProperty inside the Navigation. So everytime i navigated to a View i checked if it has set `AutoWireViewModel`to true, and if I created a ViewModel where I was able to Inject the correct Content using the Name of the Region (which is the Content.Id)

Here is where i am Stuck. The `HomeViewModel` needs to have access to the current Content it should display. I know it is possible to inject the Content via the `NavigationContext`, but the `HomeViewModel` should actually not care where the `IContent` instance comes from, it just depends on it (it is not optional so i would prefer passing it in via constructor). And the `HomeView` is just one of a lot Views that need to know the current Content, which means if I push the Content into the ViewModel via `NavigationParameters` I do either need the code that takes the Content every time, or I do need some ugly base class that takes care of taking the `NavigationParameter` and validating it contains an instance of IContent (which for me seems like "action at a distance").

How can I alter Prism Navigation and AutoWireViewModel to automatically resolve the correct instance of IContent? 
It should use something like this:

```
IContent targetContent = Container.Resolve<IContentManager>.Contents[this.RegionThatDidInvokeTheNavigation.Name]
```

Or is there a better approach to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem, and I would have liked if prism slightly modified its RegionNavigationService to give us an option to influence viewmodel creation (see https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/367).

If you don't like to implement `INavigationAware` on your viewmodel (which implies that you're left in an uninitalized state until the navigation actually happens), you could modify `RegionNavigationService.ExecuteNavigation` like this:

```
[...update journal...]

// Create and set the view model based on the navigation context
var viewAsDependencyObject = view as DependencyObject;
if (viewAsDependencyObject != null)
{
    var createViewModelOnNavigateTo = ViewModelLocator.GetCreateViewModelOnNavigateTo( viewAsDependencyObject );
    if (createViewModelOnNavigateTo)
        ViewModelLocator.Bind( view, _viewModelProvider.CreateViewModel( viewAsDependencyObject, navigationContext ) );
}

[...inform view...]
```

`_viewModelProvider` is a service that creates viewmodels from the `NavigationContext`, `CreateViewModelOnNavigate` is an attached property similar to `AutoWireViewModel`.

Comment: thanks, i already thaught about altering the prism library, but prefereable i would solve this without changing the libraries (as prism is well documented) maybe i will take the time and create a pull request for a open way to inject the functionality into prism (something like a sub container for each region wich is consumed to create the ViewModel)